# Python - Multithreading in a loop

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization

I need your advice on implementing multi thread in a loop

**Summary**

- I have a loop who needs to be executed as fast as possible
- in each loop, I had a function who made 2 checks :

  - first price check
  - second price check

--> I want those 2 price checks to be executed at the same time, to gain speed

**My sample code**

Here is what I've done:

```
(beginning of the loop)

    TH1 = Thread(target=step1, daemon=True, args=(token,))
    TH2 = Thread(target=step2, daemon=True, args=(token,))
    
    TH1.start()
    TH2.start()
    
    TH1.join()
    TH2.join()
    
    price = price1 / price2

(end of the loop)
```

My concern is that in each loop , 2 new threads are created, and I have 10 loops per second, so is it ok if thread numbers gets very, very high ?

Actual result :

```
...    
(result of the loop)
Thread-25
Thread-26
Price
Thread-27
Thread-28
(result of the loop)
Thread-29
Thread-30
(result of the loop)
Thread-31
Thread-32
(result of the loop)
Thread-33
Thread-34
(result of the loop)
Thread-35
Thread-36
(result of the loop)
Thread-37
Thread-38
(result of the loop)
Thread-39
Thread-40
... etc.
```

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: What operation do you actually perform? Threads only speed up I/O bound code and they come with some overhead (even when re-using them). If you have "10 loops per second", threads are actually pretty unlikely to be the appropriate tool.

Comment: maybe you should create treads only once and they should run loop which get value from queue, run code and return result using queue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys.
My software is a Web3.py bot, and in each step1/step2 , I call some functions like  :

client.eth.contract(address=pair_address, abi=lpAbi)
or 
pair_contract.functions.getReserves().call()

Comment: furas : I think you are right, I'll think about that

Comment: OK guys, indeed I found a MUCH BETTER solution, as furas suggested : 1/ run two threads with a "while True" loop inside   2/ create another loop who interacts with those 2 others loops. Results are amazing ! thanks a lot